# Java enhanced for loop VS .NET foreach loop

Tags: c#, java, polymorphism, foreach

I have a question to which I have not found an answer.
Let's say we have in either java or c# the following code:

```
class Car {
   /* car stuff */
}
```

And then in Java

```
class Truck extends Car {
   /* truck stuff */
}
```

and C#

```
class Truck : Car {
   /* truck stuff again */
}
```

In C# the following works just fine:

```
List<Car> carList = new List<Car>();
//add some objects to the collection
foreach(Truck t in carList)
     //do stuff with only the Truck objects in the carList collection
```

This works because Truck is a subclass of Car which in simple terms means that each Truck is also a Car. The thing is though, that type checking is done and only Trucks are selected from carList.

If we try the same thing in Java:

```
List<Car> carList = new ArrayList<Car>();
//add some objects to the collection
for(Truck t : carList)
     //**PROBLEM**
```

Because of the code inside the enhanced loop, the code will not even compile. Instead we have to do something like this to get the same effect:

```
for(Car t : carList)
   if(t instanceof Car)
      //cast t to Truck and do truck stuff with it
```

It is the same idea which in C# works without any problem, but in Java you need extra code. Even the syntax is almost the same!
Is there a reason why it does not work in Java?

Comment: This is also not so clean in C# since every Truck is a Car but not every Car is a Truck... In C# the conversion is tried at runtime, but you should be really cautious with it. Java seems to be more cautious about it and wants the programmer to check it first (of course the C# version does add some benefit if you know what you are doing).

Comment: in C# the type of each object is checked. If it is Truck, the body of the foreach loop is entered, otherwise it doesn't. What's not clean about that? Either I check it (Java) or the runtime checks it (C#) it`s the same end result.

Comment: Java Generics allows to clearly specify the objects, but if you would like to have the list which should contain any Car then you could write something like this. 
List<? extends Car> carList = new ArrayList<Truck>();

Comment: @Florian Rappl, most programmer do not know what they are doing, so i doubt that in long way run this is a benefit. Java designers had simple principal find the bus as soon as possible. In this case a exception may occur on runtime. In Java on compile time.

Comment: That the foreach loop is entered only for Trucks. If You will have for example a Bus in that list runtime will throw a exception.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The thing is though, that type checking is done and only Trucks are selected from carList.

Nope, it's not. If your list contains anything but `Truck`s, a runtime exception will occur in C#. Basically, in C#, the following

```
foreach(Truck t in carList) {
    ...
}
```

behaves like

```
foreach(object _t in carList) {
    Truck t = (Truck)_t;        // throws an InvalidCastException if _t is not a Truck
    ...
}
```

The Java variant, on the other hand, is type-safe: You have to make the cast and the type-checking yourself.

---

So, why do Java and C# behave differently? This is my guess:

C# had the `foreach` keyword before it had generics. Thus, there was no possibility to have a `List<Car>`. If C# had opted for the Java way of `foreach`, you'd have to write

```
foreach(object _c in myArraylistContainingOnlyCars) {
    Car c = (Car)_c;
    // do something with c
}
```

which is annoying. On the other hand, the extended for loop and generics were introduced in Java in the same version (Java 5), so there was no need for automatic casts.

Comment: so you mean that if the list has no Truck object in it, an exception will be thrown?

Comment: No, if there is any non-truck object in it, an exception will be thrown

Comment: gave it a try and you are right... should brush up on my C#, thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 5):

In C#, when you write

```
foreach(Truck t in carList)
```

what the compiler understands is (roughly):

```
var enumerator = carList.GetEnumerator();

while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    Truck t = (Truck)enumerator.Current;
    // do stuff
}
```

The assignment will fail at runtime if carList contains non-truck cars.

You may try the following console application to illustrate:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Car
    {
    }

    class Truck: Car
    {
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Car[] cars = new[] { new Car(), new Truck() };

            foreach (Truck t in cars)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("1 truck");
            }

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

The C# and java compilers behave differently here because different choices have been made when designing the language. Oddly enough, "failing as soon as possible, at compile time if possible" is a common guideline in the C# specifications. Here is a case where it's not applied and where, as much as I like the C# language, I prefer the java behavior.

However, in C#, linq provides an easy way to achieve the functionnality you thought it had:

```
foreach (Truck t in carList.OfType<Truck>())
{
    //do stuff
}
```

that way the enumerable will be filtered and only the trucks will make it to the loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Car> carList = new ArrayList<Car>();
//add some objects to the collection
for(Truck t : carList)
     //**PROBLEM**
```

Java Generics, introduced in Java 5, are a bit different from .NET generics.

Long story short - you can't write code like this - it is a compile-time error. **You have a list of cars and you try to get a list of Trucks - it even sounds wrong**/

The right approach is to use the `Truck` class via its `Car` interface. If you can't (not enough methods or methods have different meaning) then you could either filter the list (before iterating) or .. redesign your classes

Answer (score 1):

The program will not compiled because you using Truck class instead of Car.

No need for this one

```
for(Car t : carList) {
    if(t instanceof Car)
        // Do stuff here
}
```

You can do like this:

```
for(Car t : carList) {
    // Do stuff here
}
```

It will works if you do like this:

```
List<Truck> truckList = new ArrayList<Truck>();

for(Car car : truckList) {
    // Do stuff here
}
```

Or this:

```
List<Car> carList = new ArrayList<Car>();

for (Iterator<Car> it = carList.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    Truck car = (Truck) it.next();
    // Do stuff here
}
```

Instead of this:

```
List<Car> carList = new ArrayList<Car>();

for(Truck truck : carList) {
    // Do stuff here
}
```